# Browser Extension Development - offset page by x amount of pixels to show top nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on building a browser extension that renders a 50px high tool bar at the top of existing webpages. However, I am having issues with it looking clean and not interfering with content on the page. Ideally, I would like the bar to render in fixed or sticky position and push the page content down by 50px, and then if closed the page content will go up again by 50px. (See https://www.standardcameras.com home page for example).

The issue I'm having is that I can't predictably push everything down by 50px. This seems to vary per web page (I imagine it depends on what the topmost element is, its positioning, and what padding/margins, etc are set for the rest of the page.

I've tried setting the top margin of the body to 50px, tried the same with padding.

I've similarly tried to do so with Javascript using

document.body.style.marginTop = '50px';

Currently the code that renders the navbar is as follows:

```js
let x = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];

navBar =  document.createElement('div');

navBar.setAttribute("id", "navBar");

navBar.innerHTML = '<div id="title"><p>pwmd</p></div>';

x.insertBefore(navBar, x.firstChild);
```

```css
#navBar {
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: grey;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 15px 0px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 99999999999999;
}


#navBar p, #navBar a, #navBar h1, #navBar h2, #navBar h3, #navBar h4, #navBar h5, #navBar h6, #navBar li {
 color: white;
}

#navBAR #title {
 margin-left: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

So far, the javascript is working as expected and rendering a div with those properties at the top of the HTML body. I just can't get it to position correctly. I expect it to position at the top of the page (I'm not at this point even trying to get it to reposition the rest of the content, thats a long term goal) but sometimes it renders near the end of the page, sometimes it renders after a header, etc. How can I modify either my CSS or my Javascript to fix this?

I seriously appreciate your input.. thanks in advance!

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, it always displays on top of the page. Looks like we need more info to recreate your problem.

Comment: I'm specifically having an issue on https://www.whitney.org and https://www.moma.org

Comment: Then add all relevant HTML and CSS from one of these sites to your question so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks @cloned - I think I've actually solved this problem though and am moving on to another issue.